# Drag and drop inside the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]I want to let the div inside table be draggable to different td. But always let the div be visible in the source div(that's already works).
I want to let all the divs inside td be draggable, if someone can help.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var copyimg = document.createElement("div");
  var parent = document.createElement("conteudo");
  var original = document.getElementById(data);
  copyimg.id = original.id;
  copyimg.innerHTML = original.innerHTML;
  copyimg.style.position = "absolute";
  copyimg.draggable = "true";
  ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
  <table style="width:80%;float:left">
    <tr>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
      <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div style="background:yellow ;width:15%;float:left;margin-left:10px">
    <div class="droppable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">aaa</div>
    <div class="droppable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">bbb</div>
    <div class="droppable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3">ccc</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to let all the divs inside td be draggable, if someone can help.

Comment: your divs are dragging then what is issue

Comment: But not draggable between tds

Answer (score 0):

add ondragstart="drag(event)" and use remove() for draggable element  like below,

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
    
    function drag(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
      ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
    }
    
    function drop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      var copyimg = document.createElement("div");
      var parent = document.createElement("conteudo");
      var original = document.getElementById(data);
      if(original.classList.contains('droppable'))
      {

      }
      else
      {
        original.remove();
      }
      copyimg.id = original.id+"a";
    
      copyimg.innerHTML = original.innerHTML;
      copyimg.style.position = "absolute";
      copyimg.draggable = "true";
      copyimg.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
      ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
    }
```

```css
table, th, td {
      border:1px solid black;
      height: 40px;
      width: 80px;
    }
```

```html
<div style="width:100%">
      <table style="width:80%;float:left">
        <tr>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
          <td ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div style="background:yellow ;width:15%;float:left;margin-left:10px">
        <div class="droppable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">aaa</div>
        <div class="droppable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2">bbb</div>
        <div class="droppable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag3">ccc</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

please comment if query